# Is there any way to use global menu in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, xfce, globalmenu

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 on a laptop, which means a confined screen space and a desperate need for global menu. I've tried  I've tried [topmenu](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/use-global-menu-in-xubuntu-or-linux.html) (the classic option), but it looks like it hasn't been updated for 16.04 yet. Then I discovered that it's in the official repos, but still it doesn't work. When I try to add the plugin to a panel the only result is panel becoming opaque.

I've also tried [vala-panel-appmenu](https://github.com/rilian-la-te/vala-panel-appmenu) (the alternative version), but I failed to understand how to compile it.

Is there a way to get global menu working in 16.04, or I should just relax and wait for topmenu to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebUpd8 (the site you linked) has an [updated instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/05/how-to-get-global-menu-in-xubuntu-1604.html) to make it work in Xubuntu 16.04. Some manual configurations are required such as creating a shell script in `/etc/profile.d/topmenu-gtk.sh`.

Note that the functionality of TopMenu in Xubuntu16.04 is very limited compared to Ubuntu 14.04. It only works with GTK2 and 3 apps. Qt4 and Thunderbird support was removed. In addition, Firefox recently stopped working with TopMenu, and TopMenu have no support for Qt5, Chrome, or LibreOffice, so YMMV.

**EDIT:** [Vala Panel AppMenu PPA is now available from WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/02/alternative-global-menu-for-mate-and.html). Like TopMenu, some manual configurations are required so make sure you read and follow the instructions carefully.