# Xubuntu 16.04 xfce4-topmenu-plugin: half working

Tags: xubuntu, window, window-manager

I have just installed this plugin and make it work following [this tutorial](https://proyectosbeta.net/2016/07/como-instalar-topmenu-global-menu-en-xubuntu-16-04/). It is properly working with some apps but not with all. For example with Thunar file manager and wxMaxima it does what is supposed but with Lyx, Okular, and some others it does nothing. How can I make it work with all apps?

Comment: TopMenu only works with GTK2 and GTK3 applications. It doesn't work for Qt (4 or 5) applications as well as LibreOffice, Firefox andThunderbird.

Comment: Ok, I didn't even knew of the existence of GTK and QT. Is there some way to have a unified menubar like in Unity? I am on a laptop and want to save screen space.

Comment: Either GTK or QT can be used to build a GUI (the visual interface you interact with to use a program, instead of operating it via command line). Don't worry, if you're not a developer or a tinkerer, you wouldn't know about them...until something goes wrong :).

Comment: Try Vala Panel AppMenu (see the end of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/787382/787506))